# Inequality $\sqrt{2x^2+3} < x-a $

Tags: inequality

$\sqrt{2x^2+3} < x-a $ (I)

My try:

$2x^2+3 < x^2-2ax+a^2\\ x^2+2ax+a^2 < 2a^2 -3 \\ x+a < \sqrt{2a^2-3} \; \; \lor \; \; -x-ay\sqrt{2a^2-3} \\ x < \sqrt{2a^2-3} -a \; \; \lor \; \; x > -\sqrt{2a^2-3} -a$

Is this correct? Can I square both sides when there is an inequality?

Comment: You have to be careful when squaring both sides. In this case, since $\sqrt{2x^2+3}$ is positive, you can square both sides. Note, you are suddenly using equality in your last two lines, which is confusing.  What you kno wis $|x+a|<\sqrt{2a^2-3}$

Comment: I think you want and "and" symbol, not an "or" symbol. You want $$|x+a|<\sqrt{2a^2-3}$$ or $$-\sqrt{2a^2-3}<x+a<\sqrt{2a^2-3}$$

Comment: Don't include nothing but $\LaTeX$ in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Because $\sqrt{2x^2+3}\ge 0$, we know $x-a>\sqrt{2x^2+3}\ge 0$ as well. So since both sides are nonnegative, we can square them-however, this may lead to extraneous solutions. In this case, we must have $x\ge a$ at the end. Because your solution set is
$$
-\sqrt{2a^2-3}-a\le x\le \sqrt{2a^2-3}-a
$$
solutions are possible only if $a\le\sqrt{2a^2-3}-a$. This occurs exactly when $a\le -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ (because $\sqrt{2a^2-3}$ must be defined.) If $a\le -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$, then $$2a^2-3\le 4a^2\Rightarrow \sqrt{2a^2-3}\le \sqrt{4a^2}=-2a$$ so $a\le -\sqrt{2a^2-3}-a$. Thus we have:
$$
-\sqrt{2a^2-3}-a\le x\le \sqrt{2a^2-3}-a
$$
for $a\le -\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}$ and no solutions otherwise.